# Array formula to sum dynamic range

Tags: excel, vba

i have data that looks like
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tZJB0.png).

I want to insert an array formula, which will sum specific range based on user's choice. If the user chose for example "3", i want an array formula to Sum absolute value of 3 last columns (D,E,F) for each row (rows are also dynamic - there could be 10,50 or more rows). Last column is always in the same place, the starting point change. How can i do that?

Comment: I'm not sure you need an array formula, you just need a whole heap of dynamic processing to determine the range in which to sum.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data starts in cell A1 and the number of columns chosen is in H6 and you are using dynamic array excel then try this formula:

```
=SUM(ABS(INDEX(A1#,SEQUENCE(ROWS(A1#),1),SEQUENCE(1,COLUMNS(A1#)-H6+1,H6))))
```

To enter into cell Z9 using vba if nCols contains the number of columns try this:

```
Range("Z9").formula2="=SUM(ABS(INDEX(A1#,SEQUENCE(ROWS(A1#),1),SEQUENCE(1,COLUMNS(A1#)-" & nCols & "+1," & nCols & "))))"
```